# When ListView items are updated, how can the actual files be updated?

Tags: c#, listview

Currently, I am making an file explorer program in C#. My ListView, which displays the files in a folder, has the LabelEdit property enabled.

Now, I want to rename the file in the ListView. How can I make it so that it will be renamed in the actual Windows Explorer?

Comment: Use the AfterLabelEdit event to write your code to change the file name.

Comment: ok thanks... I shall try this.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for the event handler, but how would I code the file name change?

Comment: ListView is available in WinForms, WPF, UWP so without that one can't give you the answer.

Comment: @IvanIčin What do you mean?

Comment: @NitishVijai you haven't specified what type of user interface you use. Those above are different types and solutions are different. There are some more too, e.g. if you use C# on the web server there is also a ListView but that is probably not your case.

Comment: @NitishVIjai, also the file commands are different for Windows Store apps and the desktop apps.

Comment: @IvanIčin Sorry for not explaining, but I am using Windows Forms.